# Android: How to call ListActivity methods for class that extends MapActivity?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a class that uses both a ListView and MapView. I originally wrote the class to extend ListActivity. However, I later found out that I would need to extend MapView and then reference the ListView if I wanted to combine the two.

So, this is how is is now declared:

```
public class MapListActivity extends MapActivity {
```

Next I figured I needed a way to get at the ListView so I wrote this:

```
//instance vars
ListView listView;

//get ref to listview
listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

In line with the old code I added:

```
    listView.setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    listView.getListView();
```

However, the error I get is that the method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type MapListActivity or ListView. This makes sense for the MapView because the class extends MapActivity but I am not sure how to get it to work now that the class no longer extends ListActivity?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [ListView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

```
listView.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

should be

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also,

```
listView.getListView();
```

doesn't exist for a `ListView`. It is unclear what you want to achieve. If you want to get the item at a position, you can use [`ListView#getItemAtPosition (int pos)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29)